# How to increment every number in a vector without the error "cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time"?

Tags: vector, rust, borrow-checker

This code is supposed to increment each value in a vector by 1:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5];
    let i = v.iter_mut();
    for j in i {
        *j += 1;
        println!("{}", j);
    }
    println!("{:?}", &mut v);
}
```

It doesn't work because of the borrowing rules of Rust:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:8:27
  |
3 |     let i = v.iter_mut();
  |             - first mutable borrow occurs here
...
8 |     println!("{:?}", &mut v);
  |                           ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
9 | }
  | - first borrow ends here
```

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Hmmm, for me the code works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't store the mutable iterator; use it directly in the loop instead:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5];

    for j in v.iter_mut() { // or for j in &mut v
        *j += 1;
        println!("{}", j);
    }

    println!("{:?}", &v); // note that I dropped mut here; it's not needed
}
```

Comment: What is the scope of `v.iter_mut()` in the 4th line?

Comment: @saga the body of the `for` loop.

Comment: so we have to make use of nested scopes to deal with this restriction of rust, am I right?

Comment: @saga in case of such loops I'd say it's just the conventional and easy way, but in general yes - nested scopes can solve different borrow-checker issues.

Comment: `I'd say it's just the conventional and easy way` Are there other possible ways?

Comment: @saga of course; you could, for instance, write `for j in 0..v.len()` and then refer to `v[j]` instead of `*j`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will work as-is in a future version of Rust thanks to *non-lexical lifetimes*:

```
#![feature(nll)]

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5];
    let i = v.iter_mut();
    for j in i {
        *j += 1;
        println!("{}", j);
    }
    println!("{:?}", &mut v);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2645a333347ceeac807e1319a032d041&version=nightly)

Answer (score 0):

You call also just use `map` and `collect` like,

```
>> let mut v = vec![5,1,4,2,3];
>> v.iter_mut().map(|x| *x += 1).collect::<Vec<_>>();
>> v
[6, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the simplest and most readable solution:

```
#![feature(nll)]
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5];
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        v[i] += 1;
        println!("{}", j);
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```